# Restrict interface type parameter in method

Tags: typescript, type-variables, typescript-generics

I'm trying to convey that a method only makes sense when the type parameter of its interface honours a certain constraint. Here's a (non-compiling) example:

```
interface Array<T> {
    fold<B>(base: B, f: (acc: B, e: T) => B): B
    sum(): T is number
}

Array.prototype.fold = function(base, f) {
    let result = base
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        result = f(result, this[i])
    return result
}

Array.prototype.sum = function() {
    return this.fold(0, (acc, e) => acc + e)
};

[1, 'a', 3].sum() //? 1a3  <-- should be an error!
```

Here, I was trying to convey that `sum` only makes sense when `T extends number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, just the wrong syntax.

This is how you write it.

```
interface Array<T> {
  sum(this: number[]): number;
}
```

Notice how we used the `this` type which is a synthetic  parameter does not change the arity of the function. The syntax you attempted to use, while an interesting guess, is used for another purpose namely type guards.

The interesting part is that the type annotation on `this` takes precedence over the type of the interface. You could declare a generic parameter as well, apply it to `this`, and place restrictions on `T` so it can be composed as well. There is a ton of flexibility.

Here's an interesting one that combines both the interface type and refines it with `this`

```
interface Array<T> {
  flatten(this: T[][]): T[];
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! :D

Comment: The thing I don't honestly like is the `Array.prototype... =` stuff. It only works in concrete types, and I was looking to extend `ArrayLike`.

Comment: That's an interesting point. `Array` isn't a concrete type either, as TypeScrippt doesn't have such things. What it is is a value and a type that have the same name. There is no `ArrayLike` value. when we talk about types, we tend to conflate the value and the type but they are not connected at all. I say that because a constructor is not a type and `instanceof` is not a type test it's a reference check on a mutable property